# Google sheets simple Vlookup not working with code included

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I am trying to do a simple Vlookup like I have done many times in the past in google sheets, but this one does not work for an unknown reason.

I want to get the date in Column B.

The formula in the VLOOKUP field is  "=VLOOKUP(C3,B6:C8,1)" It says it did not find the value I am searching for.
[image]

Comment: `VLOOKUP` always work from left to right. Your formula should be `=VLOOKUP(C3,{C6:C8,B6:B8},1)`

Comment: Or maybe `VLOOKUP(C3,{C6:C8,B6:B8},2,0)`. You give very little info.

Comment: I want to get the date column in column B. I am not sure what you mean with "works from left to right".

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=VLOOKUP(C3, {C6:C8, B6:B8}, 2, 0)
```

Comment: Why the "2" I want the date, which is in the first column?

Comment: @StephanKetterer noted. answer updated. try now

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
=VLOOKUP( N1,{N4:N6,M4:M6},2,0)
```

*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

Format the cell as date

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this solution?